# Build definition for Django app in VSTS

Tags: python, django, azure, build, azure-devops

I'm looking for a functional build definition for a Django 2.0.5 app in Visual Studio Team Services.

What I'm trying to do is deploying my Django application to Azure App Services trough CI/CD, and the process is running well (I mean, the files is being traspased to production), but, for some reason, my app doesn't starts and I'm getting a lot of errors. I guess I'm traspassing the wrong files, but I really don't know it.

Can someone please tell me what did you do to build a Django app with CI/CD in VSTS?

EDIT:
What I'm doing is use a default build definition for Python called "Python package", but customized. In one of the build steps, it calls to "setup.py" file. I created the file in the root folder of my repository, and I wrote the next code:

```
import os
import shutil
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

if not (os.path.exists('./dist')):
    os.makedirs('dist')
else:
    shutil.rmtree('./dist')

copy_tree(".", "./dist")
```

Ok, I know the code is ugly, and I need to write it in a better way, but is functional and it copy the entire project structure into the "./dist" directory. Later, the release proccess takes all these files and copy it to production environment. All this works Ok, but my app never starts. When I try to navigate my url, I receive a 404 error, and can't use any of the project routes.

Hope it helps, if not, I will put all the necessary details, thank's again.

Comment: Please add what exactly you have tried, what are the error msgs etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. I didn't traspased the environment folder, and I has missed web.config file too.

Uploading the env folder and the web.config file fix the application.

ref: https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/djangoapp